# What is the alternate for List-to-List control in Pega 7.2. As it deprecated from Pega 7?

Tags: pega

*What is the alternate solution for List-to-List control in Pega 7.2. As it deprecated from Pega 7 ?*

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative. It is assumed that you will solve problems using `repeat grid`, *drag-n-drops*. Can you describe your problem more details?

Comment: Hey thanks..But i got solution on it. In PEGA 7.2 List-to-List control in deprecated So there is new "Build a List" control is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the alternative is available as part of UI-Gallery. The previous control is non-auto generated, so it has be deprecated in Pega7. When we can build the same control using declarative rules, the non-auto generated code is not required.

**NAVIGATE to UI-GALLERY**:
1. DesignerStudio > User-Interface > UI-Gallery.
2. Look for Build-A-List.
3. View design-time-configurations.

P.S. You can build this is many ways, easiest way is to move element from a data-page/page-list to another.